# Cannot install Hyper-V on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I can't start a VM (any) on my Win 8 laptop. I tried re-installation of hyper-v with no success (uninstalled Hyper-V and checked with VMWare Player and it works, so it's not a hardware issue, I guess).

Comment: do you have VMware player installed on your system when you try to start Hyper-V?

Comment: Hyper-V requires specific hardware support does your hardware meet those requirements?  The requirements are also well documented.

Comment: you have any more information, like the behaviour or error messages. "it doesn't work" is vague.

Comment: Check the system event log - you'll see messages about Hyper-v or the hypervisor etc., not starting, and why.

Comment: AbhishekGirish - I uninstalled it before installing hyper-v again. Only hyper-v is installed now.
Ramhound - I have a brand new laptop with the latest i5 - hyper-v is supported.
BroScience and Mark - this is the message:
'New Virtual Machine2' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID DE5F9FC4-6A82-4039-85E3-18A82A938FEE) Log name: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker/Admin Source: Hyper-V-Worker Event ID: 3040

Answer (score 6):

Here are requirements for Hyper-V  :

1. Hyper-V is 64-bit only and thus requires a 64-bit (x64) processor
2. Hardware Virtualization Assists in the form of: 
   Intel VT-x /
   AMD AMD-V
3. Hyper-V requires Hardware Data Execution Prevention :

Set these BIOS options to enable:

- On Intel processors this is called Execute Disable (XD).
- On AMD processors this is called No Execute (NX).

Set these BIOS options to disable:

- Intel VT-d (AMD-V) is disabled
- Trusted Execution is disabled

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) are concise instructions needed to run Hyper-V. Please check it, it is very helpful in setting up Hyper-V.

**Update**

Hyper-V Platform is available on Professional & Enterprise editions of Windows 8 only.

Comment: I followed the manual with no success (vt-d indeed needed to be disabled and I reinstalled hyper-v).
Any other good idea?

Comment: my laptop started as standard version of windows 8 and after that I upgraded to professional edition. do you know if there's some other service that should also be enabled for the hyper-v to work?

Comment: In Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs -> (Left-side panel)Turn Windows Features On or Off -> Tick Hyper-V

Comment: already done - the hyper-v manager looks ok but the vm cannot be started.