# Cannot disable Hyper-V in Windows 8.1, listed as missing

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm trying to run AndyOS. Its an Android emulator to run Android apps and games on my PC.

My system meets the hardware specifications and since I have prior experience in running virtual machines, I know a thing or two about virtualization support.

I had enabled Hardware Virtualization through the BIOS and installed the virtual machine,but it fails to start up.

I contacted AndyOS support forums and they suggested to disable Hyper-V as it would prevent the virtual machine to start. They told me to run the following command on an elevated command prompt to disable Hyper-V

**dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V**

Here's what I got

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and tr
y the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

What does this mean? Is Hyper-V having a problem in my PC, even though the PC fully supports Hyper-V?

I have "Windows 8.1 Single Language" preinstalled by OEM HP.

I am **able** to run the virtual machine with hardware virtualization **disabled** but its extremely laggy.

Comment: The command is working for me without any issue in windows 8.1 enterprise OS. But not disabling the hyper-v feature.
Have you tried by disabling Hyper-v feature going through control panel -> left side select "Turn windows features on  or off" -> deselect the feature "Hyper-v -> Hyper-v platform" and then rebooting the machine?

Comment: There isn't an option called "Hyper-V" under "Turn on Windows features on or off".

Comment: Hyper-V is only part of Pro or Enteprise edition, not the basic edition

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 dont have hyper-v - cant use Windows Phone Emulator](http://superuser.com/questions/772078/windows-8-1-dont-have-hyper-v-cant-use-windows-phone-emulator), [Cannot install Hyper-V on Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/563023/cannot-install-hyper-v-on-windows-8)